# An integral identity, general multidimensional case

Tags: integration

A follow-up to [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/394510/proof-for-an-integral-identity)  question. Which of the following equations is true? Can someone give a proof to the correct equation. Thanks.

Please note the prefactors $N$ and $N!$

$$\int_0^A dx_1 \ldots  \int_0^A dx_N \quad f(x_1) \ldots f(x_N) = N 
\int_0^A dx_1 \ldots\int_0^{x_{N-1}}dx_N \quad f(x_1) \ldots f(x_N)
\qquad \mathrm{Eq. 1}$$

$$\int_0^A dx_1 \ldots  \int_0^A dx_N \quad f(x_1) \ldots f(x_N) = N! 
\int_0^A dx_1 \ldots\int_0^{x_{N-1}}dx_N \quad f(x_1) \ldots f(x_N)
\qquad \mathrm{Eq. 2}$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second is correct. Consider the unit cube and try to see that one sixth of it satisfies $x\le y\le z$. More generally, there are $N!$ permutations of any given $N$-tuple of values, and exactly one of them satisfies $x_1\le\dotso\le x_N$.